# Datagridview vb won't work

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview

I'm doing an A Level in computing (I'm terrible at programming so thats why im here) and I followed a tutorial to get a datagridview to load up a table in the database I have linked to the project and nothing comes up in the debug, still greyed out table.

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Cards
 Dim con As New OleDbConnection

 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= |DataDirectory|\Cards.accdb"
    con.Open()
    datagridShow()
 End Sub
 Private Sub datagridShow()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM cards", con)
    da.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
    con.Close()
 End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: "I'm doing an A Level in computing (I'm terrible at programming" - perhaps switch to Geography!

Comment: That's an odd thing you are trying to do: Clicking on the text of a grid cell is supposed to change the data source of that grid.

Comment: Have you tried a break point? Your code might not be executing.

Comment: Your code executes on the `DataGridView_CellContentClick` event, wich fires when you click the text of a cell. Your DataGridView is empty at the beginning, wich means there is no cell to click, wich means there is no way the event fires, wich means your code will never execute. Put a button on your form and move your code to the `Button_Click` event.

Comment: I'm doing an A Level in Computing too, but usually in times where I'm stuck (admittedly not many) I usually go to my tutor: you should try asking yours too.

Answer (score -2):

'If there is no data in the Grid There are No Cells to click so your code won't trigger a DataGridView1.CellContentClick   So you will never hit your DataGridView1_CellContentClick method

'I just ran your code and it worked.  I did put my connection string in so check your connection 'string.

'I am not sure why you are loading the grid on the cell contact click.

'Try this and call loadData on pageload or a button click event this should work for you.

```
Private Sub loadData()
    con.ConnectionString = "Your Connection String"
    con.Open()

    datagridShow()
End Sub

Private Sub datagridShow()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM cards", con)
    da.Fill(dt)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: If this is a DataGridView and not a DataGrid then there is no DataBind method

Comment: Yes you are right I removed that I was thinking about the gridview sorry I corrected my answer

Comment: Please reconsider how you provide answers on Stack Overflow; two of your answers submitted today are low-quality.